# Handle firebase-authentication callback without firebaseui-web (next-firebase-auth)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I have been dealing with a problem for several days and do not manage to solve it well.

I am using `Firebase` and `NextJs` in my current Project.

My current goal is to log in a user with `firebase-authentication`
.
**However, it should also be possible to call the user in getServerSideProps and also to generate the IdToken within this.**

The `next-firebase-auth` package makes life a lot easier. Basically, the package allows you to do just that.

When the user signs in, an endpoint `'/api/login'` is called to generate a refresh token and store the user info, ID token, and refresh token in cookies. Future requests to SSR pages receive the user info and ID token from cookies, refreshing the ID token as needed.
I am theoretically able to perform user.getIdToken() in getServerSideProps.

There is an example scenario within the repo, but which uses the
`firebaseui-web`. This enables you to make all the customizations you need.
Within this, inside the callback, `signInSuccessWithAuthRes` is set to false. And as I understand it, the key is here, as only then there is a redirection to `'/api/login'`  to where the cookie is set.

However, I don't want to use the `firebaseui-web` as the UI looks bad.
I use the "normal way" of logging in my user with `firebase.auth()`, but I am not redirected to `'/api/login'`.
I tried to strive for the route myself, but always got an error

*Error: The request is missing an Authorization header value
(I tried to set the Firebase IdToken as Bearer Authorization, but it did not work)*

**Is there a way to achieve this, without the `firebaseui-web` ?**

***My Approach***

./pages/api/login

```
import { setAuthCookies } from 'next-firebase-auth'
import initAuth from '../../initAuth' 

initAuth()

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await setAuthCookies(req, res)
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Unexpected error.' })
  }
  return res.status(200).json({ success: true })
}

export default handler
```

Part of my loginFuntion

```
const result = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
const token = await result.user.getIdToken(true)
await axios.post('/api/login', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
```

***Example Code from next-firebase-auth GitHub Repo (FirebasAuth.js)***

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

// Note that next-firebase-auth inits Firebase for us,
// so we don't need to.

const firebaseAuthConfig = {
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  // Auth providers
  // https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configure-oauth-providers
  signInOptions: [
    {
      provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      requireDisplayName: false,
    },
  ],
  signInSuccessUrl: '/',
  credentialHelper: 'none',
  callbacks: {
    // https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#signinsuccesswithauthresultauthresult-redirecturl
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: () =>
      // Don't automatically redirect. We handle redirects using
      // `next-firebase-auth`.
**// Thats the Part I am not able to implement in my code !!!**
      false,
  },
}

const FirebaseAuth = () => {
  // Do not SSR FirebaseUI, because it is not supported.
  // https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/213
  const [renderAuth, setRenderAuth] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      setRenderAuth(true)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {renderAuth ? (
        <StyledFirebaseAuth
          uiConfig={firebaseAuthConfig}
          firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()}
        />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  )
}

export default FirebaseAuth
```

**initAuth.js (if you need)**

```
import { init } from 'next-firebase-auth'
const TWELVE_DAYS_IN_MS = 12 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000

const initAuth = () => {
  init({
    debug: true,
    authPageURL: '/auth',
    appPageURL: '/',
    loginAPIEndpoint: '/api/login', // required
    logoutAPIEndpoint: '/api/logout', // required
    // firebaseAuthEmulatorHost: 'localhost:9099',
    // Required in most cases.
    firebaseAdminInitConfig: {
      credential: {
        projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        // Using JSON to handle newline problems when storing the
        // key as a secret in Vercel. See:
        // https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/749#issuecomment-707515089
        privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY
          ? JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY)
          : undefined,
      },
      databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    },
    firebaseClientInitConfig: {
      apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
      authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
      databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
      projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    },
    cookies: {
      name: 'ExampleApp',
      keys: [
        process.env.NEXT_COOKIE_SECRET_CURRENT,
        process.env.NEXT_COOKIE_SECRET_PREVIOUS,
      ],
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: TWELVE_DAYS_IN_MS,
      overwrite: true,
      path: '/',
      sameSite: 'strict',
      secure: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COOKIE_SECURE === 'true',
      signed: true,
    },
  })
}
```